# $\sigma$ algebra question

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

So I'm learning a little bit of measure theory currently, and I am a little in the dark as to the motivation for the definition of the $\sigma$ algebra. My biggest question is why the $\sigma$ algebra must be used rather than the power set (since a $\sigma$ algebra is a proper subset of the power set, right?). I had read somewhere that it has something to do with the Banach-Tarski paradox, but I am unsure why if that is the case. Can someone help shed some light on this for me? Thanks!

Comment: In the one-dimensional case, for example, we want measure to be some kind of generalization of length.  If every set is measurable, how do you reconcile the fact that each point has measure $0$ but the unit interval has measure $1$?  Basically, it's impossible to define a measure with the desired properties if every set is to be measurable.

Comment: So how exactly does the sigma algebra fix this which I guess is what I'm wanting to ask.

Comment: Because then you just get that countable sets have measure $0$.  There's no way to get to intervals by taking countable unions of singletons.

Comment: Ah okay. Is there such a thing as taking an uncountable union of singletons to arrive at intervals on the real number line? If so, how is such a procedure denoted?

Comment: $$\bigcup_{x\in S}\{x\}=S$$

Comment: Well that's anticlimactic. Haha but thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant theorem about using the whole power set rather than some smaller $\sigma$-algebra is the following. There is no function $\mu$ assigning to every subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ an ext4ended-real number $\mu(A)\in[0,\infty]$  such that: (1) For any interval $[a,b]$ (for $a<b$ in $\mathbb R$), we have $\mu([a,b])=b-a$ (so $\mu$ agrees with our usual notion of length when the latter is available), (2) For any $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ and any $t\in\mathbb R$, we have $\mu(\{a+t:a\in A\})=\mu(A)$ (i.e., $\mu$ is invariant under translations), and (3) If $A_n$ (for $n\in\mathbb N$) are pairwise disjoint, then $\mu(\bigcup_nA_n)=\sum_n\mu(A_n)$.

In other words, there is no "reasonable" measure defined on the whole power set of $\mathbb R$.  There is, however, a reasonable measure defined on the "nice" subsets of $\mathbb R$, and the meaning of "nice" here is broad enough to encompass the sets people (or at least analysts and probabilists) normally need to work with. The idea is to use (1) above to define $\mu$ on intervals and then use (3) (and its consequence that, if $A\subseteq B$ then $\mu(A)\leq\mu(B)$) to extend $\mu$ to lots of other sets. Roughly speaking, the sets that get assigned a measure this way are the Lebesgue measurable sets, and they form a $\sigma$-algebra.

It turns out that lots of other situations lead to measure functions defined on $\sigma$-algebras. For example, if you had a material object with density $\rho$ varying in space, then there would be a measure, as described above, except it's defined on "nice" subsets of space $\mathbb R^3$ and, in place of (1) you'd have $\mu$ agreeing with ordinary mass on rectangular boxes. Similarly for probability densities. So the $\sigma$-algebra context is broad enough to cover lots of important situations.

On the other hand, the $\sigma$-algebra context is narrow enough to allow proofs of useful theorems. Specifically, this context allows us to impose requirement (3) above, countable additivity, on measures, and that requirement plays a role in numerous proofs.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! This answer was very clear! Another related question I have is: Does any of this arise from accepting the axiom of choice? I have read that the B-T paradox is a result of this, and I was wondering if it was somehow related?

Comment: The theorem I stated in the first paragraph of my answer depends on the axiom of choice (AC). So discarding AC might look  like a good idea, but it's not. In set theory without AC, the real line, though uncountable, might be the union of countably many countable sets, in which case there's no hope for a countably additive nontrivial measure. A possible solution is to assume a weak form of AC, adequate for proving things like "Lebesgue measure is countably additive" but not for producing non-measurable sets. But then keeping track of what applications of AC are "legal" becomes a nuisance.

Comment: Wow that sounds pretty complex haha. Thanks for your answer! It was really helpful! And can you recommend a good book to read for set theory that will help me learn more about the mathematical details of these kinds of things?

Comment: I'd suggest starting by looking up the "Vitali set" (in books about measure theory or on line); it's the standard example of a set of real numbers that isn't Lebesgue measurable. For material on what is and what isn't provable with weakened versions of AC or without AC altogether, there are Jech's book "The Axiom of Choice" and Howard and Rubin's "Consequences of the Axiom of Choice." Another good source is Eric Schechter's AC web page at https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/ccc/choice.html .

Answer (score 2):

$\sigma$ algebras are defined this way so that a suitable measure can be defined on them. It’s impossible to define a reasonable measure on the power set of $\mathbb R$ or many other sets, because you can always find sets which can’t be assigned a proper value (in a similar way to the Banach-Tarski paradox, where the sum of values of the pieces should simultaneously be “twice” the sphere and “all” of the sphere).

Comment: Oh okay so how does a sigma algebra remove the sets that can't be measured? And couldn't we just redefine our measure in some way that allows for the unmeasureable sets to be measured?

Comment: @user132849 I won’t go into details about it but it is possible to prove that no measures on the power set of the reals exist. $\sigma$ algebras are important because all measures are $\sigma$ algebras; for more details see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Σ-algebra

Comment: Okay thank you so much for your answer!